# Why validator is showing error for same field in edit mode in angular reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have a requirement to have a unique name field. I am using same form for user registration and edit mode.

My validation logic sends request to backend and brings all the usernames available and store them in an array list. And when user enter username
the entered username is compared with the existing usernames from database. If found, validation comes in and validation error is displayed
like "Username already exists!!!"

My user form is as below:

```
  createUserForm() {
    this.userRegistrationform = this.fb.group(
      {
        id: [null],
        name: [null, Validators.required, CustomValidators.userNameValidator(this.userService)], //username validator placed
      }
    );
  }
```

These are code in CustomValidators class:

```
static existingUserNames: [];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.storeUserNames();
  }


 checkIfUserNameExists(value: string) {
    return of(UserService.existingUserNames.some((name) => name === value)).pipe(
      delay(1000)
    );
  }

  public storeUserNames() {
    this.getAllUserNames().subscribe((data) => {
      UserService.existingClientNames = data;
    })
  }
  
//async validator to validate if username already exists
 static userNameValidator(userService: UserService): AsyncValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
            return userService
                .checkIfUserNameExists(control.value)
                .pipe(
                    map((result: boolean) =>
                        result ? { userNameAlreadyExists: true } : null
                    )
                );
        };
    }
```

Below is how I have caught error in html file:

```
 <span *ngIf="form.name.hasError('userNameAlreadyExists')">
       User name already exists!!!
 </span>
```

Problems:

1. If I enter username in user register mode like "name : John + space" and add space after name it works. So why it is working only after I add space in name value in user register mode?
2. As I am using same form for edit mode as well, username field shows error "User name already exists!!!" error and invalidates whole form directly if I open form in edit mode. Why is this happening?

Any kind of suggestion or solution would be great. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

#### First point

A first tip, add a `trim` function in order to check only the exact value

```js
 static userNameValidator(userService: UserService): AsyncValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
            return userService
                .checkIfUserNameExists(control.value.trim()) // added trim
                .pipe(
                    map((result: boolean) =>
                        result ? { userNameAlreadyExists: true } : null
                    )
                );
        };
    }
```

And I usually add the `touched` check

```html
 <span *ngIf="form.name.hasError('userNameAlreadyExists') && form.get('name').touched">
       User name already exists!!!
 </span>
```

But I think the problem is with the `delay`, try to convert it to `timer`

```js
 checkIfUserNameExists(value: string) {
    return timer(1000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => of(UserService.existingUserNames.some((name) => name === value)) 
    )
  }
```

##### Second point

To be sure that the form was in its initial state, you can call the `reset` method:

```js
this.form.reset()
```

I tried to replicate your behavior here (with the possible fix):
[Aysnc validator reset](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hymk3w?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestion after adding trim there is no problem in register mode but in edit more it does not show the validation error promptly because of touched condition I added  but the form remains invalid and problem is still there in edit more.

Comment: I don't know your behavior but a form should trigger the validation only if the user clicks on the input or try to submit the form

Comment: Yes validation kicks in If I am in edit mode while submitting or if I click in username field in the form. The error is set as "Username already exists!!!" which I do not want it to be while I am editing the form. I just want the form to not set error as above in edit mode.